# Finding source line on exception (Android, Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

When the Eclipse debugger stops due to an exception in my Android project, I can see the exception message in the variables window (e.g., "null pointer"), but how can I find out what Java code line my app was at when the exception occurred?

I can see a stack trace in the LH window, but selecting any of them doesn't seem to reveal anything that relates to my code.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the `LogCat` view (in Eclipse `Window-->Show View-->Other...-->Android-->LogCat`) or in the `adb logcat` output from a terminal.  The place to look will likely be the first mention of one of your classes below the line:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( ####): Caused by:
```